# how to have the brightness icon displayed on acer laptop screen

Tags: laptop, screen, acer, icons, brightness

I used to have a meter icon displayed on my Acer laptop screen when changing brightness or volume with the hotkeys - it would show the level of adjustment. I don't know what has been turned off or disabled since (maybe something in startup disabled?), but now the icon is no longer displayed on screen but I can still adjust the levels with the hotkeys. Please help me and let me know how to get the brightness and volume meter icon to display on screen again.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd suspect your computer's BIOS settings. Reboot, Hit F2, and **CAREFULLY** explore the settings, looking for "OSD" (OnScreenDisplay). I don't have an Acer laptop of the same model (whatever that is). If you use a Fn key (Fn+Up/Dn Arrow), it's the BIOS,

Answer (score 1):

i would try to (re)install the packet notify-osd. In a terminal invoke:

```
sudo apt-get install notify-osd
```

If the package is already installed check whether it is running using:

```
ps aux | grep notify-osd
```

If it is not running, try to start it using:

```
/usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd
```

I hope this helps you.

Greetings from Switzerland, Michael K